# How can we connect different instances of database in a same Application?

Tags: sql-server-2008, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

guys this is my question:
                          How can we connect different instances of database in a same Application

i am using Silverlight,MsSQL 2008 (BackEnd),WCF ria services

can any one help me out please....

Answer (score 2):

Create multiple data models (e.g. Entity Framework, Linq2SQL, etc), specifying the correct connection string for each one.